# area of a bounded region

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region bounded by $$f(x)=x^3+x^3+1$$ and $$g(x)=x^2 + x-1$$ I do know how to get the area of a bounded region, my problem now is that when I tried getting the graph of this region I realized that it isn't bounded. Do I still get an area of this one? or this is mistakenly written? or there is another way of finding the area? Because I think it is violating the fact that it should be bounded. Please help. I've been stuck in this problem..

Comment: $x^+$...? Is that not $x+$?

Comment: $x^3+x^3+1$? That's an odd way to write $2x^3+1$; going by the earlier version maybe it should be $x^3+x+1$? In either case there isn't any bounded region between the graphs, so I expect that there is an error in the question.

Comment: yes, the question is stated as is and it's really not bounded when i should be looking for the area of a bounded region.. so i guess i should not continue solving it.. thanks everyone!

Comment: It appears possible that the first curve equation was intended to be $ \ f(x) = x^3 -x^2 + 1 \ \ , $ since the "intersection equation" $ \ x^3 - x^2 + 1 \ = \ x^2 + x - 1 \ $ factors nicely as $ \ (x^2 - 1) · (x - 2) \ = \ (x + 1) · (x - 1) · (x-2) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ giving two _bounded_ regions over which to integrate with integer limits.  The function $ \ f(x) = x^3 -x + 1 \   $  is also possible, with two of the limits becoming $ \ x = -\sqrt2 \ , \ x - 1 \ $ and $ \ x = \sqrt2 \ \ . $  Instructors setting problems should really make sure they can be solved _before_ passing them to students...

Answer (score 0):

IF:

$$f(x)=x^3+x^\alpha+1 \, \& \, g(x)=x^2+x-1 ; \alpha=1$$then the functions only intersect at (-1,-1) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l8qwlmz3qz

So, you need to evaluate:

$$\int_{-1}^{\infty} [(x^3+x-1) - (x^3+x+1)] dx$$ and obviously that is divergent and technically the area between those functions is infinite. 
We can also see that the integral will be divergent for any $$\alpha \in N$$